# How to use ss in specific network namespace

Tags: networking, linux-networking, containers, network-namespace

Whilst investigating some TCP network issues in containers I tried to use `ss` to peek into container network TCP stack.

We are running Amazon Linux in AWS:

```
# uname -a
Linux 4.14.173-137.229.amzn2.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Apr 1 18:06:08 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`ss` has the following cli switch for that:

```
       -N NSNAME, --net=NSNAME
              Switch to the specified network namespace name.
```

`lsns` gives me the following output:

```
# lsns | grep net
4026531993 net       225     1 root      /usr/lib/systemd/systemd --switched-root --system --deserialize 21
4026532284 net         2 26244 root      /pause
```

This is `pause` container created for each `Kubernetes` pod -- it's the container that creates the network namespace.

Trying to peek into the pod network namespace by running `ss`:

```
# ss -tp -N 4026532284
Cannot open network namespace "4026532284": No such file or directory
```

What's interesting is  `ip netns list` does not return any network namespaces:

```
# ip netns list
#
```

Is there any way how one can look into K8s pod network namespaces from the root network namespace i.e. from the netns 1?

```
# ss --version
ss utility, iproute2-ss180129

# lsns --version
lsns from util-linux 2.30.2

# rpm -qi iproute
Name        : iproute
Version     : 4.15.0
Release     : 1.amzn2.0.4
Architecture: x86_64
Install Date: Sat 07 Mar 2020 03:42:24 AM UTC
Group       : Applications/System
Size        : 1321292
License     : GPLv2+ and Public Domain
Signature   : RSA/SHA256, Fri 21 Feb 2020 09:00:29 PM UTC, Key ID 11cf1f95c87f5b1a
Source RPM  : iproute-4.15.0-1.amzn2.0.4.src.rpm
Build Date  : Fri 21 Feb 2020 07:56:50 PM UTC
Build Host  : build.amazon.com
Relocations : (not relocatable)
Packager    : Amazon Linux
Vendor      : Amazon Linux
URL         : http://kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/net/iproute2/
Summary     : Advanced IP routing and network device configuration tools
```

**Update: Tue Dec  1 11:35:39 UTC 2020**

After some struggle, I finally decided to `strace` this.

It turns out `ss` is an awesome tool, but when it comes to using it with containers it leaves a bit to be desired, but I feel there is more than one "culprit" involved.

`ss` does not bother to look up the actual PID of the process that creates the network namespaces, but rather goes directly to check `/var/run/netns`:

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/var/run/netns/4026532284", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(2, "Cannot open network namespace \"4"..., 70Cannot open network namespace "4026532284": No such file or directory
) = 70
```

Now, I suspect this is due to how `iproute` package creates `network namespaces` i.e. given the `ss` is shipped with `iproute` package the assumption `ip` makes about network namespaces is: "hey all network ns should be found in `/var/run/netns` directory, because, like, why not and also this will make lives of `iproute` devs easy, or whatever.

Turns out that's a false assumption made on `ss`/`iproute` side or the lack of "agreement" on modern containers tools and `iproute` interoperability, but it kind of explains the empty output from

```
ip netns list
```

So the way `ip` creates network namespaces (so they can be inspected by `ss`) obviously does not match how kubernetes and the likes create them, making `iproute` package utilities borderline useless in the grand scheme of things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more generic way is to use [`nsenter(1)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/nsenter.1.html).

```
nsenter -t ${PID_FOO} -muni ss -tpi
```

A go to approach is using something like the following, when needing to run adhoc stuff, that do not necessarily have support for [`unshare(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/unshare.2.html)/[`setns(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setns.2.html) built-in.

```
docker run -it --rm --security-opt=seccomp:unconfined \
                    --security-opt=apparmor:unconfined \
                    --privileged --pid=host --userns=host \
debian:jessie@sha256:51cd80bb935b76fbbf49640750736abc63ab7084d5331e198326b20063e7f13c \
nsenter -t ${PID_FOO} -m -u -n -i -F ss -tpi
```

Comment: I like this (except for the ginormous `sha` tag) because it does not require modifying the host filesystem, unlike what my answer suggests. Thanks!

Comment: Why `-m` (mount), `-u` (uts) and `-i` (ipc)? Just `-n` should suffice, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use `ss` to peek into a particular container namespace here is how you do it:

1. Find out the PID of the container process
   `ps aux` or `ps -ef` should give you the answer
2. Create the following symlink

```
ln -s /proc/PID/ns/net /var/run/netns/mycontainer
```

3. Profit

```
ss -tpi -N mycontainer
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a recent version of **lsns**, you can use options **-n -o NSFS** to convert a namespace inode into the ID used by the network subsystem.

For example, let's say you have net NS 4026536974. You can run:

```
sh-4.4# lsns --version
lsns from util-linux 2.32.1
sh-4.4# lsns -n -o NSFS 4026536974 | sort -u                                                                                                                                                                                                 
/run/netns/d0912eba-0fae-425c-94ba-cf270aa23c93
sh-4.4# basename /run/netns/d0912eba-0fae-425c-94ba-cf270aa23c93                                                                                                                                                                             
d0912eba-0fae-425c-94ba-cf270aa23c93
sh-4.4# ss -nltp -N d0912eba-0fae-425c-94ba-cf270aa23c93 | head -2                                                                                                                                                                           
State     Recv-Q    Send-Q       Local Address:Port        Peer Address:Port                                                                                    
LISTEN    0         128                0.0.0.0:5000             0.0.0.0:*        users:(("nginx",pid=874035,fd=5),("nginx",pid=874028,fd=5))                    
sh-4.4#
```

Or all in one:

```
sh-4.4# lsns -n -o NSFS 4026536974 | sort -u | xargs -rn1 basename | xargs -rn1 ss -nltp -N | head -2                                                                                                                                        
State     Recv-Q    Send-Q       Local Address:Port        Peer Address:Port                                                                                    
LISTEN    0         128                0.0.0.0:5000             0.0.0.0:*        users:(("nginx",pid=874035,fd=5),("nginx",pid=874028,fd=5))                    
sh-4.4#
```